# Что означает формулировка "#!" в href атрибуте ссылки?

Tags: html

Недавно в одном коде нашёл строчку:

```
<a href="#!/main" class= >
```

Что за зверь такой `#!`? Сам я нагуглить не смог, прошу вашей помощи. Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://www.articlesworld.ru/articles/webmaster/16_30/tega.php).

Answer (score 7):

Это не html тэг, а просто часть пути, ведущая на site.com/main. Зверь '#!' это hashbang, который использует тот же Angular для замены html5 history api (это на тему того, что гуглить). Сам же # в урле - это просто якорь на какой-то участок указанной страницы, см например [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya).

update: [ссылка на перевод](http://angular.ru/guide/dev_guide.services.$location) оф. документации angular, где можно посмотреть параграф "Hashbang и режим HTML5"

Comment: Спасибо! А то я ни как не мог найти в коде элемент с именем "!/main".